# How should I handle "real time" events in an online strategy game?

Tags: online, strategy, realtime

Some online strategy games have real time events. For example when you send troops to attack somewhere, the attack happens at the right time in the future. Checking the database again and again to get the list of attacks happening each second would cause heavy load. Is there any technique to achieve this goal?

Another example: You want to attack a village 3 hours away, you send troops and the attack occurs 3 hours later. Should there be an script to check the database at each second to run the query at the specified time?

Comment: What is the specific problem *you* are trying to solve for *your* game? Asking only about how other games implement some feature is trivia, and generally off-topic.

Comment: Related (based off what I think you're asking): [Implementing a build queue in a browser based game](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49308/) and [How to update a game off a database](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30080/how-to-update-a-game-off-a-database) And you might want to list some technologies if you want slightly more specific answers. Essentially, you should use an event scheduler.

Comment: The server can maintain a sorted list of upcoming events and push them to the client at the right time.

Comment: The title of the question I linked seems unrelated, but my answer to this question will be almost identical.  Calculate events upon request when a user is actually interacting with the system, not silently in the background needlessly.